# Arguments for Commands in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

So obviously there are arguments for commands and registering a command like

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand("bla", (arg1: any, arg2: any) => {});
```

brings `arg1` with a strange object containing only one key and that's `context`; an object holding some information about - you guessed it - the context.

There is also no way for the user to specify arguments. Not through the command palette and not for keybindings.

So are those arguments only for internal stuff or are they supposed to be used by an extension developer?

Comment: Besides context, what are you trying to bring in? Remember these commands will be triggered by a string from the user through a command pallet actions or keyboard shortcut. From there, you can gather the context or ask for input.

Comment: I wrote an extension where you can copy selected text to registers. When triggering the `copy to register` command the user is asked to which register the text should be copied. But when using the keyboard it would be handy to use key cords and then directly specify a registers by key (a, b, c, etc.). To achieve this I currently have to create multiple commands alá `copyToReg1` and then the number of registers a user can have is technically bound to the number of commands, that I create. Wouldn't it be nice to just pass the register as a string parameter specified in the `keyboard.json`?

Comment: Why not create a drop down list for the user in one command? You are just as limited by number of free keys as possible commands, but your idea seems to make more sense as one command with a list. Then user can type first litter and search/select the one they want with a couple of key strokes. Even better, they won't have to memorize a chord

Comment: Hi @Databyte did you manage to solve this? So far seems that the functionality to achieve this is simply not there :(

Comment: Hi @LeoGallucci unfortunately it looks like you're right :( you can not pass arguments from kedboard.json

Answer (score 7):

In `keybindings.json` you can specify arguments as such:

```
{
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "key": "alt+d",
    "args": "docker"
}
```

To access `keybindings.json` open `View` > `Command Palette` and type/choose `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`. You may also want to assign a keyboard shortcut to this command.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty hack:
If you don't mind how the command shows up in the editor, you can pass arguments, like ${file}, as the "name" in your launch.json. Then you just grab it from the context like so:

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand('extensiontest.helloWorld', (context) => { 
   
    type ObjectKey = keyof typeof context;
    const argsKey = 'name' as ObjectKey;
    console.log(context[argsKey]);
    ...
```

As a side effect, the name of the launch configuration in the drop down list will be {file}, or whatever your arguments are.

I want to stress that this is awful, but I believe it does answer the question.